# What is the equivalent of git commit -a for git add

Tags: git

`git commit -a` automatically stages all modified files:

```
-a
--all

     Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified
     and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected.
```

What is the equivalent of `-a` for `git add`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent would be `git add -u`